# Trying to paste a lowest price from G2A onto google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

So I am trying to learn how to get the lowest selling price data from g2a games and put it onto google sheets.  I tried the code below for Next car Game on G2A but get an error saying imported content is empty.
=IMPORTXML("https://www.g2a.com/next-car-game-early-acces-steam-cd-key-global.html","//div[@class=mp-Price]")

I am very new to this but hope to learn off of this

Comment: Welcome to SO! Removed excel tag as this is a google sheets question.

Comment: The URL you've supplied contains a `span` with this class, not a `div`: `<span class="mp-Price">$37.69</span>`.

Comment: so is there something i am able to change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It is loaded by a separate json file through jquery. I found the source url but you will still have to parse out that data and then compare lowest rates potentially

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTDATA("https://www.g2a.com/marketplace/product/auctions/?id=5759&v=0"))
```